# Recommended way to handle AngularJS Promises between Service and Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code shown below works for my purposes, but I'd like to confirm if this would be considered best practice.

I want my factory to make a http request for profile information in the first instance, but then to simply reuse this data on subsequent requests.

ProfileService.js

```
app.factory('ProfileService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var profile;

    return {
        getProfile: function() {
            if (profile === undefined) {
                return $http.get('url/to/profile.json').then(function(response) {
                    profile = response;

                    return profile;
                });
            }

            return $q.when(profile);
        }
    };
}]);
```

I have two controllers that then utilise the ProfileFactory to access elements of this data.

HomeController.js

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['ProfileService', function(ProfileService) {
    var self = this;

    ProfileService.getProfile().then(function(result) {
        self.name = result.name;

        self.showAlert = result.showAlert;
    });
}]);
```

ProfileController.js

```
app.controller('ProfileController', ['ProfileService', function(ProfileService) {
    var self = this;

    ProfileService.getProfile().then(function(result) {
        self.profile = result;

        self.profile.showAlert = false;
    });
}]);
```

Any feedback on this approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the best way to cache data with the help `$q.when`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best approach. Having the service return a promise for controllers to use is the best separation of concerns imo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes having the http call in the service is best. Traditionally we hold the promise rather than the data, like this:

```
app.factory('ProfileService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var profilePromise;

    return {
        getProfile: function() {
            if (profilePromise === undefined) {
                profilePromise = $http.get('url/to/profile.json');
            }
            return profilePromise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @koolunix. I started with this approach and then ran in to issues as I have multiple controllers that want to share and manipulate the response data, which led to me storing this in the factory.